# How do i create Foreign Key relationship in .netframework 3.5/Code First Model?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, c#-3.0

I have below data contract with foreign key relation with my .net framework 4.0 project. I want to re-use the same code for .net framework 3.5 project. But i am dll missing error for ForeignKey attribute. How do i rewrite the below code for .netframework 3.5? Kindly help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
Using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace xyz {
    [DataContract]
    public class Category
    {       
        public string category_id { get; set; }  

        public string category_name { get; set; }    

        public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategorys { get; set; }
    }


    [DataContract]

    public class SubCategory 
    {
        public string sub_category_id { get; set; }
        public string sub_category_name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubCategory2> SubCategory2s { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("category_id")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SubCategory2 
    {
    public string sub_category2_id { get; set; }
    public string sub_category2_name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("sub_category_id")]
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: which EF version u r using? the problem code first is complied with a higher then .net 3.5 SP1

Comment: If you absolutely, imperatively have to build this in .Net 3.5 I'd port it to LINQ to SQL. Otherwise you have to use EF 1 - not good.